Android Room Many to Many relationship with multiple filters
So I have a ChildEntity and a TagEntity. I can use @Relation to filter all the childEntity for a tagId. But then I want to do further filtering based on some fileds in childEntity. And there is no direct way to do it? Do I have to filter further in my viewmodel or like in my repo and not in my database?
I have tried looking android documentation, i have looked at a few stackOverflow questions, but i didn't found anything for my usecase.

Please [edit] your question and add a [mre] demonstrating what you have so far and what you want to achieve.

When using @Relation only the filtering that affects the @Embedded objects is of relevance. The @Relation objects returned are ALL related objects per @Embedded object retrieved.
You can either filter the returned objects or you can bypass the convenience of the @Relation by utilising functions that cater for the filtering via SQL.
There are basically two ways:-

you can handle the output from the single query directly, noting that the output will be the cartesian product and will contain a row per parent/child combination or,
you can have 2 queries, the first to retrieve the parent objects, the second to retrieve the filtered children.

this is similar to how @Relation handles but it does not cater for passing filter information, the function with a body does (see demo).




The latter method is typically simpler

Perhaps consider the following Demo:-
First 2 @Entity annotated classes Parent and Child (obviously related):-
@Entity
data class Parent(
    @PrimaryKey val parent_id: Long?=null,
    val parent_name: String
)
@Entity(
    indices = [ Index(value = ["parent_id_of_related_parent"])],
    /* Optional but suggested */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            Parent::class, parentColumns = ["parent_id"],
            childColumns = ["parent_id_of_related_parent"],
            /* Optional within a Foreign Key (cascade most likely useful options)*/
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Child(
    @PrimaryKey val child_id: Long?=null,
    val parent_id_of_related_parent: Long,
    val child_name: String
)


i.e. there is a 1-many relationship between Parent and Child
the relationship is enforced via Foreign Key encoding i.e. a Child MUST be related to a Parent.

Next a POJO that includes an @Relation annotation and thus an @Embedded annotation for the parent.
/*POJO*/
data class ParentWithChildren(
    @Embedded
    val parent: Parent,
    @Relation(
        entity = Child::class, parentColumn = "parent_id", entityColumn = "parent_id_of_related_parent"
    )
    val list_of_children: List<Child>
)

Now some DAO functions all in a single @Dao annotated interface:-
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(parent: Parent): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(child: Child): Long
    @Transaction
    /* Note filter (WHERE clause on child_name has no effect in regard to filtering children BUT may effect the parents extracted) */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM parent JOIN child ON child.parent_id_of_related_parent = parent.parent_id WHERE child.child_name LIKE :filterValue")
    fun getParentAndChildrenViaATRelation(filterValue: String): List<ParentWithChildren>

    /* Not typically used by itself */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM child WHERE parent_id_of_related_parent=:id AND child_name LIKE :filterValue")
    fun getChildren(id: Long,filterValue: String): List<Child>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM parent JOIN child ON child.parent_id_of_related_parent = parent.parent_id WHERE child.child_name LIKE :filterValue")
    fun getParentFilterByJoinedChild(filterValue: String): List<Parent>

    @Transaction
    @Query("") /* dummy query so @Transaction is applied */
    fun getParentsWithFiltereredChildren(filterValue: String): List<ParentWithChildren> {
        val rv: ArrayList<ParentWithChildren> = ArrayList()
        for(p in getParentFilterByJoinedChild(filterValue)) {
            rv.add(ParentWithChildren(p,getChildren(p.parent_id!!,filterValue)))
        }
        return rv
    }
}


Especially note the getParentsWithFiltereredChildren function, which is untypical in that

the @Query is empty,
the function has a body
the function invokes other @Query annotated functions, these, in conjunction, bypassing the typical @Relation generated sub queries, and instead invoking defined/coded sub queries.



Now consider the following activity code (note for brevity the main thread is used):-
const val TAG="DBINFO"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        val maryId = dao.insert(Parent(parent_name = "Mary"))
        val fredId = dao.insert(Parent(parent_name = "Fred"))
        val sueId = dao.insert(Parent(parent_name = "Sue"))
        val tomId = dao.insert(Parent(parent_name = "Tom"))

        dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Alan", parent_id_of_related_parent = maryId))
        dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Claire", parent_id_of_related_parent = maryId))
        dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Jenny", parent_id_of_related_parent = maryId))
        dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Bert", parent_id_of_related_parent = fredId))
        dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Arthur", parent_id_of_related_parent = fredId))
        dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Peter", parent_id_of_related_parent = sueId))
        dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Penny", parent_id_of_related_parent = sueId))
        dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Beth", parent_id_of_related_parent = tomId))
        dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Harry", parent_id_of_related_parent = tomId))

        val fv = "%A%"

        logPWCList(dao.getParentAndChildrenViaATRelation(fv),"R1")
        logPWCList(dao.getParentsWithFiltereredChildren(fv),"R2")
    }

    fun logPWCList(pwcl: List<ParentWithChildren>,tag_Suffix: String) {
        for (pwc in pwcl) {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for (c in pwc.list_of_children) {
                sb.append("\n\tChildName=${c.child_name} ID is ${c.child_id} PARENTID is ${c.parent_id_of_related_parent}")
            }
            Log.d(
                "${TAG}_${tag_Suffix}",
                "ParentName is ${pwc.parent.parent_name} ID is ${pwc.parent}. There are ${pwc.list_of_children.size} Children extracted. They are:-${sb}"
            )
        }
    }
}

So 4 parents are added.

The first Mary has 3 children (Alan, Claire and Jenny)
Fred has 2 children Bert and Arthur,
Sue also has 2 Peter and Penny
Tom also has 2 Beth and Harry

So the intention is to filter according to children's names having an a hence the variable fv being set to '%A%' (LIKE is not case sensitive).  As such the underlying query includes a JOIN to mimic the attempt at filtering at the child level BUT note that the resultant output will be a row per combination (which as will be shown is not as per expected). *i.e. caution should be taken when coding JOIN.
As can then be seen data is extracted and output to the log for each methodology (@Relation and function with a body submitting the subqueries).
The output in the log being:-
2024-09-23 10:01:13.626 D/DBINFO_R1: ParentName is Mary ID is Parent(parent_id=1, parent_name=Mary). There are 3 Children extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Alan ID is 1 PARENTID is 1
        ChildName=Claire ID is 2 PARENTID is 1
        ChildName=Jenny ID is 3 PARENTID is 1
2024-09-23 10:01:13.627 D/DBINFO_R1: ParentName is Mary ID is Parent(parent_id=1, parent_name=Mary). There are 3 Children extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Alan ID is 1 PARENTID is 1
        ChildName=Claire ID is 2 PARENTID is 1
        ChildName=Jenny ID is 3 PARENTID is 1
2024-09-23 10:01:13.627 D/DBINFO_R1: ParentName is Fred ID is Parent(parent_id=2, parent_name=Fred). There are 2 Children extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Bert ID is 4 PARENTID is 2
        ChildName=Arthur ID is 5 PARENTID is 2
2024-09-23 10:01:13.627 D/DBINFO_R1: ParentName is Tom ID is Parent(parent_id=4, parent_name=Tom). There are 2 Children extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Beth ID is 8 PARENTID is 4
        ChildName=Harry ID is 9 PARENTID is 4


As can be seen ALL children per parent are extracted wether or not they include an a or A

Additional/other than probably anticipated extracts appear, susch as Mary being extracted twice (as there are 2 names (Alan and Claire) that have an a in them)
Sort of as expected no data has been extracted as Sue (parent_id is 3) does not have an children with an a, thus there is no JOIN between Sue and any children.



Now compare the output from the second that bypasses @Relation handling
2024-09-23 10:01:13.634 D/DBINFO_R2: ParentName is Mary ID is Parent(parent_id=1, parent_name=Mary). There are 2 Children extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Alan ID is 1 PARENTID is 1
        ChildName=Claire ID is 2 PARENTID is 1
2024-09-23 10:01:13.634 D/DBINFO_R2: ParentName is Mary ID is Parent(parent_id=1, parent_name=Mary). There are 2 Children extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Alan ID is 1 PARENTID is 1
        ChildName=Claire ID is 2 PARENTID is 1
2024-09-23 10:01:13.634 D/DBINFO_R2: ParentName is Fred ID is Parent(parent_id=2, parent_name=Fred). There are 1 Children extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Arthur ID is 5 PARENTID is 2
2024-09-23 10:01:13.634 D/DBINFO_R2: ParentName is Tom ID is Parent(parent_id=4, parent_name=Tom). There are 1 Children extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Harry ID is 9 PARENTID is 4


Like the first the JOIN results in 2 Mary's and no Sue
However, children without an a have been filtered out (due to the filtering by the sub query).


Continuation/Additional for M2M

In short the similar applies i.e. @Relation gets ALL children. So basically the same techniques can be applied either filter the objects or bypass @Relation.
So consider the following additions to the demo:-
First the mapping table to facilitate the M2M relationship (in this case irrespective of the existing 1-M):-
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["map_to_parent_id","map_to_child_id"],
    /* not required BUT can improve efficiency */
    indices = [Index("map_to_child_id")],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(Parent::class, parentColumns = ["parent_id"], childColumns = ["map_to_parent_id"],
            onUpdate = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE, onDelete = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE
        ),
        ForeignKey(Child::class, parentColumns = ["child_id"], childColumns = ["map_to_child_id"],
            onUpdate = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE, onDelete = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE
        )
    ]
)
data class ParentChildMappingTable(
    val map_to_parent_id: Long,
    val map_to_child_id: Long
)


long winded as would be suggested i.e. FKEY definitions and index on the 2nd part of the primary key

The POJO:-
/* many-many POJO */
data class ParentAndChildrenViaMappingTable(
    @Embedded
    val parent: Parent,
    @Relation(
        entity = Child::class,
        parentColumn = "parent_id",
        entityColumn = "child_id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            ParentChildMappingTable::class,
            parentColumn = "map_to_parent_id",
            entityColumn = "map_to_child_id"
        )
    )
    val children: List<Child>
)


also suits not bypassing @Relation handling like the previous example
of course with a M2M either could be considered parent so you could have a ChildandParentsViaMappingTable POJO if need be.

Some extra DAO functions:-
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(parentChildMappingTable: ParentChildMappingTable): Long
@Query("SELECT * FROM parent")
fun getAllParents(): List<Parent>

@Transaction
@Query("")
fun getPWithCViaMappingFilteringC(filterValue: String): List<ParentAndChildrenViaMappingTable> {
    val rv: ArrayList<ParentAndChildrenViaMappingTable> = ArrayList()
    for (p in getAllParents()) {
        val iv: ArrayList<Child> = ArrayList()
        for (c in getChildren(p.parent_id!!,filterValue)) {
            iv.add(c)
        }
        rv.add(ParentAndChildrenViaMappingTable(p,iv))
    }
    return rv
}


note this time no JOIN just get all parents

And now some additional activity code to add mapped data:-
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(maryId,alanId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(maryId,claireId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(maryId,jennyId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(fredId,bertId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(fredId,arthurId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(sueId,peterId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(sueId,pennyId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(tomId,bethId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(tomId,harryId))

    val dianaId = dao.insert(Parent(parent_name = "Diana"))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(dianaId,alanId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(dianaId,arthurId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(dianaId,harryId))

    val ingridId = dao.insert(Parent(parent_name = "Ingrid"))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(ingridId,dao.insert(Child(child_name = "Erica", parent_id_of_related_parent = ingridId))))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(ingridId,pennyId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(ingridId,jennyId))
    dao.insert(ParentChildMappingTable(ingridId,bertId))

Last activity code to extract via the M2M filtering children that include an a in their name:-
    for (pwc in dao.getPWithCViaMappingFilteringC(fv)) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for(c in pwc.children) {
            sb.append("\n\tChildName=${c.child_name} ID is ${c.child_id}")
        }
        Log.d("${TAG}_M2M","Parentname is ${pwc.parent.parent_name} ID is ${pwc.parent.parent_id}. There are ${pwc.children.size} Children Extracted. They are:-${sb}" )
    }

The resultant logged data (additional):-
2024-09-23 11:41:27.471 D/DBINFO_M2M: Parentname is Mary ID is 1. There are 2 Children Extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Alan ID is 1
        ChildName=Claire ID is 2
2024-09-23 11:41:27.471 D/DBINFO_M2M: Parentname is Fred ID is 2. There are 1 Children Extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Arthur ID is 5
2024-09-23 11:41:27.471 D/DBINFO_M2M: Parentname is Sue ID is 3. There are 0 Children Extracted. They are:-
2024-09-23 11:41:27.471 D/DBINFO_M2M: Parentname is Tom ID is 4. There are 1 Children Extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Harry ID is 9
2024-09-23 11:41:27.472 D/DBINFO_M2M: Parentname is Diana ID is 5. There are 0 Children Extracted. They are:-
2024-09-23 11:41:27.472 D/DBINFO_M2M: Parentname is Ingrid ID is 6. There are 1 Children Extracted. They are:-
        ChildName=Erica ID is 10

As can be seen only children with an a in the name are extracted BUT if there are none are even no mapped children then this is reflected via 0 children being reported.

of course these could be eliminated either within the first query or later at the object level.

